# Show or hide an image based on position (Image Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

I have an image slider set up and working and what I need now is to show or hide an image based on the position of an element within the slider.

Looking in firebug, I can see the following (please note there are several li items and I am just showing one here):

```
<li class="roundabout-moveable-item" style="position: absolute; left: 128px; top: 104px; width: 185.9px; height: 188.1px; opacity: 1; z-index: 145; font-size: 8.3px;">
```

Now depending upon that 'left' position, I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
if left > 400px then add a class which will show image one,
if left < 300px then add a class which will show image two,
if left >= 300px and <= 400px then add a class which will show no image
```

All help is greatly appreciated.  I'm pretty new to JQuery but so far I am thinking:

```
var left = $("li.roundabout-moveable-item").position.left;
$("li.roundabout-moveable-item").addClass("no-image");
if(left < 300px) {
    $('li.roundabout-moveable-item").addClass("image-one");
}
elseif(left > 400px) {
    $('li.roundabout-moveable-item").addClass("image-one"); 
}
else {
    $('li.roundabout-moveable-item").addClass("no-image");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XZXPh/ check this link and put your images check your code.

Comment: Okay, so I've updated the jsfiddle, it seems that the only class being added is the .no-image class.

This is being applied to all list items so the 'left' position of the list item is clearly not being picked up.

Can anyone offer any ideas why?

Comment: Okay I can see that if I add an alert(left); to my code, that it is showing up as undefined.

Comment: Okay so updated .position.left; to .position().left and now I am getting a value returned upon the alert. The correct value!

However, now it is applying the class image-one to all li items, so it thinks all items have a left position of 200.

Comment: Actually what I need to do is loop through and determine this for each list item.

I think currently it is just executing the code for the first list item and then halting.

Comment: A wee bit stuck now.

Could someone please offer some guidance on how to loop through all my list items.  I know it will have something to do with each() but I cannot get it working.

Thanks

Comment: oh here's the link to jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/XZXPh/79/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "px" from your code and correct syntax.
I think you need sth like this:

```
var left = $(".roundabout-moveable-item").position.left;
if(left < 300) {
$(".roundabout-moveable-item").addClass("image-one");
}
else if(left > 400) {
$(".roundabout-moveable-item").addClass("image-two"); 
}
else {
$(".roundabout-moveable-item").addClass("no-image");
}
```

Comment: Hmm I guess you can't actually add a class to a class so it needs to be added to the list item itself?

Will edit my original

Comment: By using addClass method your original class (roundabout-moveable-item) will not be removed. There will be 2 classes in your html element separated by space. It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Ihor, I think just to clarify I was adding the class to .roundabout-moveable-item instead of li.roundabout-moveable-item

Is the first still valid?

Comment: You can change in my code .roundabout-moveable-item to li.roundabout-moveable-item. The only difference would be in case you have a lot of elements (not only 'li') with this class.

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense.  In this case the only element that has this class is an li element.

Comment: Hi Ihor, please see my comments above and the jsfiddle.

The no-image class is being applied to all list items so the position of the list item is somehow not being picked up.

Thanks